# Unix TimeStamp Convertir a +02:00

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo la siguiente fecha `1535440000` la estoy convirtiendo de tal forma a Timestamp:

```
recvTime: new Date(params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value * 1000).toISOString()
```

El problema es que tengo que convertir esa fecha a +2 horas. En estos momentos tengo:

```
"recvTime" : "2018-08-28T06:17:47.000Z"
```

Necesitaría comprobar la zona horaria antes de la conversión. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo para obtener un +2 en la hora?

Lo correcto sería esto: `"recvTime" : "2018-08-28T08:17:47.000Z"`

He probado con la librería Moment, pero no he sacado nada.

Gracias, un saludo.

**EDIT01**

Codigo :

```
var data_inver = [];
     var asociar_inver = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < params.contextResponses.length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes.length; j++) {
         for (var k = 0; k < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas.length; k++) {
           var medidas_inver = {
              id_greenhouse : params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.id,
              attrName : params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].name.concat("-",params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.id),
              attrType: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].type,
              attrValue: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].value,
              recvTimeTs: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value,
              recvTime: new Date(params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value * 1000).toISOString()
           };
           data_inver.push(medidas_inver);
           console.log('Mostramos las medidas:' + JSON.stringify(data_inver));
         }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Unix Time siempre es +00 (que es lo que significa la Z al final), ten cuidado con eso

Comment: Entonces me recomiendas dejarlo en base de datos? y a la hora de recuperar la información en la consulta convertirlo al +02:00?

Answer (score 0):

podrias solo agregar al unix time este tiempo

```
2*60*60*1000
(hora) * (minutos) * (segundos) * milisegundos(1000)
```

que serian 2 horas en milisegundos, solo agrega ese tiempo al UNIX time y deberia funcionar.

en tu codigo seria asi

```
recvTime: new Date(params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value * 1000).toISOString() + 2*60*60+1000
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, he probado esto y no funciona.

Comment: mmmm, mi pregunta, solo quie res aumentar el UNIX time que obtienes no? pense que seria fecha = 1535440000 + 2*60*60*1000

Comment: Correcto solo el Unix Time

Comment: podrias poner el codigo de como lo obtienes en tu pregunta :D

Comment: Añadido:)......

Comment: ya hice el update a mi respuesta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83599/discussion-between-carlosgub-and-manolait).